# How to display to attributes in a select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I show the boolean active attribute for each Vehicle in my dropdown?
i.e.  camry  - active
      jeep   - deactivated
      accord - active

`= select("drivers_vehicle", "vehicle_id", Vehicle.accessible_by(current_ability).all.collect { |o| [o.name, o.id] })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= select("drivers_vehicle", "vehicle_id", Vehicle.accessible_by(current_ability).all.collect { |o| ["#{o.name} - #{o.active ? 'active' : 'deactivated'}", o.id] })
```

Comment: Ah.  Yup.  And actually you may want o.active? ? 'active' : 'deactivated'

Answer (score 0):

```
= select("drivers_vehicle", "vehicle_id", Vehicle.accessible_by(current_ability).all.collect { |o| ["#{o.name} - #{o.active}", o.id] })
```